# Como realizar gráficos no r com títulos variáveis?

Tags: r, gráfico

Eu preciso criar uma função que me retorne gráficos em que o nome do título contenha o nome da variável, como no exemplo.

```
Dados<-c(5,4,8,9,2,1,6,2,5)

Validação <- function(y){
  plot(y, main='Gráfico y')
 }

Validação(Dados)
```

o resultado deveria ser um gráfico com título "Gráfico Dados"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obter o real nome da variável você precisa usar `deparse(substitute(y))` no título do gráfico:

```
Validação <- function(y){
  plot(y, main= paste('Gráfico', deparse(substitute(y))))
}
```

Isso vale tanto para os gráficos do pacote `base`, como para o `ggplot2` e `lattice`...

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado